# Nodejs/socket.io/express chatroom, across different ports

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I had a google and searched stack but haven't found anything relating to what I need. I have a user side of the chat(port: 3000) then I have admin side of the chat (port:3001). In the user side they enter name and other details into a form and join the chat.
    After they do this they appear in the admin side of the chat, an admin can then click on the room, enter and start chatting... Now I have the following for admin to join the room if it was on the same port, but unsure how to get them into the room when it is on a different port(these are the specs I have been given and cant change them):

admin client side:

```
$('body').on('click', '.chatroom', function(){
      var chatroom = $(this).attr('data-room');
      console.log('Chatroom client side: '+chatroom);
      socket.emit('switchRoom', chatroom);
});
```

admin server side:

```
socket.on('switchRoom', function(newroom){
    console.log('New Room: '+newroom);
    socket.join(newroom);
    socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'you have connected to '+ newroom);
    socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username+' has left this room');
    socket.room = newroom;
    socket.broadcast.to(newroom).emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', username+' has joined this room');
});
```

If you need the user side of the code then I will add it in, not sure exactly if you would as this is my first nodejs app, still figuring it all out.

Thanks!

Comment: would you not need to to somehow communicate with your admin client, and instruct the client to initiate a new connection on the user port? I'm not sure what your app setup is like, but I solved a similar issue by simply placing admins for specific rooms (say `myRoom`) in both the `myRoom` and `myRoom_admin` rooms.

Comment: Clients initiate connections so if your client wants to initiate a new connection on another port, it is free to do so in the client code.  For your admin purpose, you would just have to authenticate that connection so you knew it was an authorized user, probably using a token or cookie provided by the previous regular connection.  If you are using multiple ports, you will have to make sure your server is enabling cross origin communication or the browser will block the communication on any port that is different than what the web page is using.